# Lemoon CMS - Create site structure programmatically

Tags: c#, sql, content-management-system, lemoon

In my dev environment I have few pages, forms creating via Admin profile in Lemoon.
Now I need to install Lemoon in production server. And it will be great to run some SQL script, C# code to create site structure with pages, default values to content type pages directly after installation without any manually actions from Admin profile.

Is it possible?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can absolutely create content programmatically with Lemoon. You can do it with a simple command line project or by adding a custom [app](http://www.lemoon.com/developers/programming/extensions/applications) with a page and button for creating site content etc.

Comment: Could you provide any example or link with example? It is not clear for me.

Comment: Did you check the link about [custom apps](http://www.lemoon.com/developers/programming/extensions/applications) in my answer. Once you have a custom aspx page at ~/lemoon/admin/apps/default.aspx you can do whatever you want. For instance use the [ContentService](http://www.lemoon.com/developers/programming/api/services/content-service) to create pages etc.

Comment: Thanks. So, as I understand: 1. I must create new custom menu item Extras. 2. Add pages, content creation using ContentService in ~/lemoon/admin/apps/default.aspx page ?

Comment: Yes. That should work just fine. Another way to transfer data into production is simply to set up the site at your dev machine and then take a database backup that you can restore in your production environment.

Comment: And I can create site structure - folders, pages using ContentService?

Comment: Yes. ContentService has methods for creating pages etc.